# sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter: Format for name of embedded form

Tags: symfony1, overriding, decorator, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Im trying to create a custom formatter in Symfony 1.4. 
I have embedded form via

```
$this->embedRelation('User','BasesfGuardUserAdminForm');
```

Is there a way to format the name of the embedded form 'User'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is most straight-forward! (and pretty obvious too!)

```
$this->embedForm('inner_form', new InnerForm());
$this->widgetSchema['inner_form']->setLabel('');
```

This will result in an empty label for the form!

Comment: $this->widgetSchema['inner_form']->setLabel('&nbsp;');

tried & tested!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `BasesfGuardUserAdminForm AS User`.

Comment: Hi Crozin, u didn't get me...
When the form renders, the view is:

>>>> User <<<<
Username:
Password:
Password Again:...

I am talking about the marked 'User' which is the name of the embedded form. How can this be removed?

Comment: Maybe what you want to achieve is merged form, not embed one?

Comment: Correct, mergeform does solve that problem. But then there are a few other things that will be difficult to do. I was wondering if using the custom formatter the form name can be formatted (ignored)

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue, and when I replaced embedForm() by mergedForm() the errors became easy to manipulate.

Comment: But merge form brings along other issues - and difficulty in saving data automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $answers as $a )
{
    $aForm = new QuestionAnswerForm($a);
    $this->mergeForm($aForm);
}


$this->widgetSchema->getFormFormatter()->setRowFormat('%field%%help%%hidden_fields%');
```